# p / primes[i] >= primes[i] logic behind this

Tags: arrays, c

So from the tutorials I've been following this is code to find the prime numbers between 3 and 100 using array.
What is the logic behind the p / primes[i] >= primes[i] condition in the second for loop?

For example if I follow the loop taking p = 5 and apply the condition it'll be 5 / primes[1] >= primes[1]:

Since we know primes[1] = 3 this will become 5 / 3 >= 3 which immediately becomes false.
there  should be a test to ensure the value of p does not exceed the sq root of primes[i]
but here p / primes[i] >= primes[i] there is sq root of primes[i]

```
enter code here



int primes[50] = { 0 };
int primeIndex = 2;

bool isPrime;

// hardcode prime numbers
primes[0] = 2;
primes[1] = 3;

for (p = 5; p <= 100; p = p + 2)
{
    isPrime = true;

    for (i = 1; isPrime && p / primes[i] >= primes[i]; ++i)
        if (p % primes[i] == 0)
            isPrime = false;

    if (isPrime == true)
    {
        primes[primeIndex] = p;
        ++primeIndex;
    }
}

for (i = 0;  i < primeIndex;  ++i)
     printf("%i  ", primes[i]);

printf("\n");
return 0;
```

}

Comment: As the primes are positive anyway, multiply with `primes[i]` on both sides of the inequation you get the usual test `primes[i]*primes[i] <= p`. Note that you don't need to test primes larger than sqrt(p) to test if p itself is prime. Note, too, that aborting this inner loop does not abort the outer loop, so you'll continue the same with next larger p (7, 11, ... until p reaches 100).

Comment: `a^2 <= b <=> a <= b/a <=> b/a >=a`, who invents unreadable code like this?

Comment: Side note: I'd really prefer `break`ing the loop instead of checking the `isPrime` variable again and again. If you are willing to apply `goto` (well, hot discussion in advance, but here it appears to me a fine example for a valid application) the `isPrime` variable gets obsolete entirely...

Comment: @Dominique `a^2 <= b` requires a larger integer type (twice the number of bits) to store the intermediate result `a^2` compared to `a <= b/a`. Ignoring this causes wrong behavior only for large values of `a` which can be tricky to catch and troubleshoot. So it is debatable which version is "unreadable".

Comment: @nielsen: your reaction is the exact reason why source code comments have been invented :-)

Comment: p / primes[i] >= primes[i] why it is written like this instead p / primes[i]>= sqroot of primes[i] something like this

Answer (score 0):

The logic is that:

1. In every pair of factors (m_1, m_2), either m_1 <= m_2 or m_2 <= m_1
2. If a number n has a multiplicative factor m_1, it also has a factor m_2 = n / m_1. So factors are actually paired: m with n/m.
3. Due to (1.+2.), if m is a factor n such that m > n/m, then n/m must also be a factor of n such that (n/m) <= n/(n/m) .

So it's enough to search for the "small" factors, to verify there are no larger ones.

Comment: I didn't get it would you elaborate with example's

Comment: p / primes[i] >= primes[i] why it is written like this instead p / primes[i]>= sqroot of primes[i] something like this

Comment: @rosterrz: It would actually be more efficient to compute the square root once and compare against that. But using the condition of being the smaller factor works just as well.

Comment: still can you please explained using some example what u have explained above.

Comment: @rosterrz: If m > sqrt(n), then m^2 > n, and thus m/n must be <= m.

Comment: If a number n has a multiplicative factor m_1, it also has a factor m_2 = n / m_1. So factors are actually paired: m with n/m.  for example n=15  m2=5,15=n/m1=15/1,3.       Due to (1.+2.) what's this?? , if m is a factor n such that m > n/m, then n/m must also be a factor of n such that (n/m) <= n/(n/m) . m>n/m=3>15/5,then n/m factor such (n/m)<=n/(n/m) ==(15/3)<=15(15/3) which is false also in code totally different can u do this with 3,5,7,9

Comment: p / primes[i] >= primes[i] can u explain by putting values into it

Answer (score 0):

> ... there should be a test to ensure the value of `p` does not exceed the sq root of `primes[i]` ...

No. It is the other way around: "test to ensure the value of `primes[i]` does not exceed the sq root of `p`"

Or: "test to ensure the value of `primes[i]` squared does not exceed `p`".

---

**Only iterate to √p**

To only iterate to the root of `p`, instead of `p / primes[i] >= primes[i]`, code could consider the similar:

```
p >= sqrt(primes[i])
// or 
p >= primes[i] * primes[i]
```

- `sqrt(primes[i])` brings in floating point math.  `sqrt()` is not *specified* to be exact, just *close*.  FP math is also expensive compared to integer math.  When using `long long`, more rounding woes occur.
- `primes[i] * primes[i]` risks overflow and *undefined behavior* when `p` is near `INT_MAX`.
- `p / primes[i] >= primes[i]` (or preferably as `primes[i] <= p / primes[i]`) has neither problem.  Its computation costs may be scant as a good compiler will see the next `p % primes[i]` and perform both calculations for about the cost of one.