# Printing prime numbers using arrays

Tags: arrays, c, boolean

This is the code to print prime numbers.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int main()
{
    int p;   
    int i;
    int primes[50] = { 0 };
    int primeIndex = 2;
    bool isPrime;

    // hardcode prime numbers
    primes[0] = 2;
    primes[1] = 3;

    for (p = 5; p <= 100; p = p + 2) {
        isPrime = true;

        for (i = 1; isPrime && p / primes[i] >= primes[i]; ++i)
            if (p % primes[i] == 0)
                isPrime = false;

        if (isPrime == true) {
            primes[primeIndex] = p;
            ++primeIndex;
        }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < primeIndex; ++i)
         printf ("%i  ", primes[i]);

    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

I do not understand a few things in this code:

How does the condition in inner for loop work and what is the use of the `isPrime` variable?

Comment: The boolean is to terminate the loop when the first divisor is found. If the candidate is proved not to be prime, there is no point finding another divisor. The other condition `p / primes[i] >= primes[i]` is to prevent it iterating beyond the square root of the candidate. Why? Suppose `p` is `15`. We would find `3` as a divisor, so there is no point continuing to test `5`.

Comment: Hardcoding 2 makes sense so that `p` can be incremented in steps of 2 (try only odd numbers) and starting with `i=1` thus makes sense because there is no need to test if 2 is a divisor. Hardcoding 3 does not make sense to me. Btw, this question discusses the exact same code: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69764736/p-primesi-primesi-logic-behind-this

Comment: Use braces - it stops you getting caught with your trousers down

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code correctly computes and prints all prime numbers below or equal to 100.

> Why is it necessary to hard-code 2 prime numbers (2 and 3)?

`2` is a special case: it is the only even prime number. `2` is hard-coded as the first prime number so the outer loops only tests odd numbers.

`3` is hard-coded so the outer loop can rely on the array contents for its stop condition `p / primes[i] >= primes[i]`. There needs to be at least one odd prime number in the array to avoid an extra test on the array index, such as `i < primeIndex`.

As *chux* commented, the inner loop could start at index `i = 0` and then only `2` needs to be hard-coded into the array. The screening process will be slightly less efficient as all numbers will needlessly be tested as divisible by 2, which can be skipped as all numbers tested are known to be odd.

> What is the use of boolean expression in the first `for` loop?

The condition test in the first `for` loop is `p <= 100`. The program enumerates primes below or equal to `100`. The `primes` array has a length of `50` which is enough for this range. If the range was much larger, the array size would need to be extended.

The boolean variable `isPrime` is used to store the result of the primality test. It is initialized as `true` and will be reset to `false` if and only if a prime divisor is found in the inner loop.

The variable is tested after the inner loop to check whether `p` should be appended to the list of prime numbers.

The condition in the second `for` loop `isPrime && p / primes[i] >= primes[i]` is an optimisation: it allows the loop to stop as soon as a divisor is found.  This test could be simplified as `p / primes[i] >= primes[i]` and the loop would continue testing prime divisors up to the square root of `p`. Adding `break` statement when a divisor is found is an alternative to stop the loop early for more efficiency.

> Can someone explain me how the inner for loop works?

The inner loop iterates on prime divisors until one is found to have a 0 remainder (`p % primes[i] == 0`) or until the divisor is larger than the square root of `p` (`p / primes[i] >= primes[i]`).

Note that the array `primes` need not be initialized.

Here is a simplified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int main() {
    int primes[50];
    int i, p, primeIndex;

    // hardcode 2 prime numbers
    primes[0] = 2;
    primes[1] = 3;
    primeIndex = 2;

    // enumerate odd numbers from 5 to 100
    for (p = 5; p <= 100; p = p + 2) {
        // use a boolean variable that will be set to false if p is composite
        bool isPrime = true;

        // test all odd prime divisors up to the square root of p
        for (i = 1; p / primes[i] >= primes[i]; ++i) {
            if (p % primes[i] == 0) {
                isPrime = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        // if p is prime, add it to the array.
        if (isPrime) {
            primes[primeIndex++] = p;
        }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < primeIndex; ++i)
         printf("%i  ", primes[i]);

    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Here is an even simpler version using a function:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

// test if an odd number greater than 3 is a prime
bool isOddPrime(int p, const int *primes) {
    for (int i = 1; p / primes[i] >= primes[i]; ++i) {
        if (p % primes[i] == 0)
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}

int main() {
    int primes[50] = { 2, 3 };  // hardcode 2 prime numbers
    int primeIndex = 2;

    for (int p = 5; p <= 100; p = p + 2) {
        if (isOddPrime(p))
            primes[primeIndex++] = p;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < primeIndex; ++i)
         printf("%i  ", primes[i]);

    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: In inner for loop p/prime[i]>= prime[I] , if we use the values it will become 5(p)/ 3(prime(1) >= 3 primes(1). After this loop should be terminated. Why it doesn't terminate the loop?

Comment: Disagree with _needs_ in  "There needs to be at least one odd prime number in the array".  Could use  `primes[0] = 2; for (p = 3; p <= 100; p = p + 2) { isPrime = true; for (i = 0; ...`.

Comment: @Deepak: the first iteration for `p=5` starts with the test `5 / 3 >= 3` which is false, so the loop stops and the body is not executed and `isPrime` stays `true`, which is correct as 5 is a prime.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica: you are absolutely correct. I shall refine the answer.

Comment: @Deepak: not exactly. By construction the array `primes` contains all primes up to the current value tested : the initial values `2` and `3` are prime and all subsequent odd numbers are tested and stored if prime. `p` is assumed to be prime (`isPrime = true;`) until a division in the inner loop proves that it is composite. All odd primes up to (and including) the square root of `p` are tested in this loop, so if none of them divides `p`, `p` is proven to be prime.